# Full button in Bootstrap 4.5 Card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

While executing the below code, Click Me is being displayed when the mouse is on it (hover).

Actually I need the Click Me to be displayed to the whole card (list).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item">
        <li class="">Click Here</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    <img src="" alt="Demo">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Know more about this feature</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Detailed Explanation of this feature</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Will be thankful if the `card-body` is only displayed when "Know more about this feature" is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To have **Click Me** to be displayed all the time, remove `list-group-item` class in the `<a>` tag.

Change

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary list-group-item">
```

To

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">
```

2. card-body is only displayed when "Know more about this feature" is clicked. This can be done with jquery code and a `hide` class to control the display of the card-body. Please see code snippet for details.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li.list-group-item").click(function() {
    $("div.card-body").toggleClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary ">
        <!-- Add in task icon -->
        <li class="">Click Here<span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-tasks "></i></span></li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    <img src="" alt="Demo">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Know more about this feature</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="card-body hide">
      <p class="card-text">Detailed Explanation of this feature</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

3. Update to add in the task icon on the right of Click Here

Comment: Thanks, it works the way I need. Could you please help me for `<span class="align-items-end"><i class="fas fa-tasks "></i></span>`. I need tasks icon after Click Here text but in the right side. I tried as mentioned but didn't work.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code snippet. I hope I understand you well.

Comment: Thanks, it helped totally. I hope you can answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62236104/13647970

Comment: I have updated the answer in your post. Please check it out. I configured the nav as the flex and the child as the flex items and then reorder it with media query detection.