# New navbar if less space in Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Code (Using Bootstrap 4.5):

```js
$(".self-first-ul").append('<li class="nav-item">A long sentence here, which does not fit on small screens.</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/project/">Name</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav self-first-ul">
  </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href=""><img src="" alt="" title="" width="30" height="30" loading="lazy" />&nbsp;
          <span>1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How my Code Shows:-

When Screen is big:-

[image: Big Screen]

When Screen is small:-

[image: Small Screen]

**How I want when the screen is small:-**

[image: Small Screen Expectation]

I tried to add extra navbar after the first navbar, but then it was not looking good when screen was big. And also, overlapping the first navbar in the small screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the jquery code to perform the task you desire. Please run and see the code snippet for details.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".self-first-ul").append('<li class="nav-item">A long sentence here, which does not fit on small screens.</li>');

  function updateFlexConfiguration(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
      $("nav").css("display", "flex");
      $("a").css("order", 0);
      $("button").css("order", 1);
      $("ul").css("order", 2);
    } else {
      $("nav.navbar").css("display", "flex");
      $("a").css("order", 0);
      $("ul").css("order", 1);
      $("button").css("order", 2);
      $("div").css("order", 2);
    }
  }
  const navBarPadding = 32;
  var navItemsWidth = $("a").outerWidth(true) + $("button").outerWidth(true) + $(".self-first-ul").outerWidth(true) + navBarPadding;
  var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: " + navItemsWidth + "px)");
  updateFlexConfiguration(x); // Call listener function at run time
  x.addListener(updateFlexConfiguration); // Attach listener function on state changes

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/project/">Name</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav self-first-ul">
  </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href=""><img src="" alt="" title="" width="30" height="30" loading="lazy" />&nbsp;
          <span>1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Update: To center the long text

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add text center to align the text
  $(".self-first-ul").append('<li class="nav-item text-center">A long sentence here, which does not fit on small screens.</li>');

  function updateFlexConfiguration(x) {
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
      $("nav").css("display", "flex");
      $("a").css("order", 0);
      $("button").css("order", 1);
      $("ul").css("order", 2);
      $("ul").css("flex-grow", 1); // to take up remaining space so that text can be centered
    } else {
      $("nav.navbar").css("display", "flex");
      $("nav.navbar").css("justify-content", "space-between"); // Set space between the flex-items
      $("a").css("order", 0);
      $("ul").css("order", 1);
      $("ul").css("flex-grow", 0); // Set ul not grow with the remaining space
      $("button").css("order", 2);
      $("div").css("order", 2);
      $("div").css("flex-grow", 0); // Set div not grow with the remaining space
    }
  }
  const navBarPadding = 32;
  var navItemsWidth = $("a").outerWidth(true) + $("button").outerWidth(true) + $(".self-first-ul").outerWidth(true) + navBarPadding;
  var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: " + navItemsWidth + "px)");
  updateFlexConfiguration(x); // Call listener function at run time
  x.addListener(updateFlexConfiguration); // Attach listener function on state changes

});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/project/">Name</a>

  <ul class="navbar-nav self-first-ul">
  </ul>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href=""><img src="" alt="" title="" width="30" height="30" loading="lazy" />&nbsp;
          <span>1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Do you know why the sentence is not in the center when screen is large? (just run your code in Full Page view, you will get what I am trying to say.)

Comment: The output is expected because `<div>` `.navbar-collapse` class is having `flex-grow: 1` property. This means it will grow to take up the remaining space. Do you want it to be center? We can modify it with some flex configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can show or hide specific elements in your HTML depending on the responsive utilities of bootstrap doc's: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/

Check the "**d-none d-md-block d-xl-block**" or "**d-block d-sm-block d-xs-block d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none**" ....

The following example should require your needs somehow, though you will have to play around with it to find your solution:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

        <!-- Will be shown for bigger viewports -->
        <div class="d-none d-md-block d-xl-block">Header viewport md + xl</div> 

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>      

      <!-- Will be shown for smaller viewports -->
      <div class="d-block d-sm-block d-xs-block d-md-none d-lg-none d-xl-none">Header viewport sm + xs</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```